# tikz-feynman: lenght of the first line is different

Tags: tikz-feynman

I want to set the lenght of the lines of my Feynman diagrams made with `tikz-feynman`, here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% LuaLaTeX is used
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]

    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \begin{feynman}
                
            \vertex (a) {\(g\)};
            \vertex[right=1cm of a] (b);
            \vertex[below right=1cm of b] (c);
            \vertex[below left=1cm of c] (d);
            \vertex[left=1cm of d] (e) {\(g\)};
                
            \vertex[right=1cm of b] (f) {\(t\)};
            \vertex[right=1cm of c] (g) {\(H\)};
            \vertex[right=1cm of d] (h) {\(\overline{t}\)};
                
            \diagram*{
                (a) -- [gluon] (b),
                (b) -- [anti fermion] (c),
                (c) -- [anti fermion] (d),
                (d) -- [gluon] (e),
                    
                (b) -- [fermion] (f),
                (c) -- [scalar] (g),
                (d) -- [anti fermion] (h),
            };
          
        \end{feynman}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

As you can see the top left line (gluon) is shorter than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably caused by the way you defined your vertices. Vertex `e` is defined depending on vertex `d`, not depending on vertex `a`. Here's a way to avoid this kind of issue: create your vertices form left to right and don't forget to give two parameters when you say `below right =`.

[image: Feynman diagram]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% LuaLaTeX is used
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]

    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \begin{feynman}
                
            \vertex (a) {$g$};
            \vertex[below=2cm of a] (e) {$g$};
            \vertex[right=1cm of a] (b);
            \vertex[below right=1cm and 1 cm of b] (c);
            \vertex[right=1cm of e] (d);
                
            \vertex[right=1cm of b] (f) {$t$};
            \vertex[right=1cm of c] (g) {$H$};
            \vertex[right=1cm of d] (h) {$\overline{t}$};
                
            \diagram*{
                (a) -- [gluon] (b),
                (b) -- [anti fermion] (c),
                (c) -- [anti fermion] (d),
                (d) -- [gluon] (e),
                    
                (b) -- [fermion] (f),
                (c) -- [scalar] (g),
                (d) -- [anti fermion] (h),
            };
          
        \end{feynman}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```